# Getting xhr poll error with socket.io on desktop only

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm making a multiplayer game on the web using socket.io, but only I've gotten this error on desktop (not on phone).
The Full error is

> socket.min.io.js:6 GET http://my.public.ip:8080/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ndge5Hh net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I Found the xhr poll error by doing this:

```js
socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
    console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
});
```

it shows `connect_error due to xhr poll error`

I've done all the port forwarding correctly.

Strangely I was running 2 servers on the same file (but adding two event listeners), one of the servers works perfectly but the other one doesn't so I thought that the same file was the problem so I unmerged them into seperate files, but the error still showed up.

Here are both the server files:

```js
//Login.js THE ONE THAT WORKS

const httpServer = require("http").createServer();

const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://my.website",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});

const port = 8081;

io.on("connection", (client) => {
    console.log(`${client.id} joined`)
});

httpServer.listen(port);
```

```js
//Game.js THE ONE THAT DOSENT WORK
const httpServer = require("http").createServer();

const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://my.website",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});


io.on("connection", (client) => {
    console.log('joined')
});

httpServer.listen(port);

Update(); //A Function Thought this might be useful
```

EDIT:
I FOrgot to add the client javascript so here it is:

```
//Connecting to Game.js
const socket = io("http://same.ip.checked:8080");//Ive tried http / https / none they all dont work


socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("connected");
})
```

```
//Connecting to Login.js (One that works)
const socket = io("same.ip.checked:8081");

socket.once("connect", () => {

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that that the port `0808` was being used by my servers router as a default gateway, so i changed the port and everything worked (: